# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I added this code in script files. I got error in my second line.
I changed the $ instead of jquery also but i got above error. Please suggest where i made mistake

```
      if(jQuery(window).width()>=320){
 jQuery(".side-nav-button").on("click tap", function() {
                            jQuery(".side-nav-container").toggleClass("showNav hideNav").removeClass("side-nav-hide");
                            jQuery(this).toggleClass("animated");
                        });
      }  
     }
    };
  }(jQuery));
```

Thanks

Comment: Try using $ instead of jquery and check

Comment: To make your life easier, before posting validate your code in a linter in order to catch obvious errors: http://jshint.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is the valid code for this:

```
$(function(){
    if($(window).width()>=320){
     $(".side-nav-button").on("click tap", function() {
       $(".side-nav-container").toggleClass("showNav hideNav").removeClass("side-nav-hide");
       $(this).toggleClass("animated");
     });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       if(jQuery(window).width()>=320){
 jQuery(".side-nav-button").on("click tap", function() {
                            jQuery(".side-nav-container").toggleClass("showNav hideNav").removeClass("side-nav-hide");
                            jQuery(this).toggleClass("animated");
                        });
      }(jQuery);
```

It seems in your code there is extra brackets in your code.

Answer (score 0):

- Use '$' instead of 'jQuery' hope it will work
- Put your jQuery script first before all scripts `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js" ></script>`